# proxy asp does not load external xml

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, xml, rss

i'm trying to load remote rss feed with jquery and a (aspx) proxy. I read a lot of questions on this matter but mine is slightly different.
I have an XML file which contains user's subscriptions. For each entry i want to load some feeds, say the first 3 feeds.
I can correctly retrieve the list of subscriptions but i can't get feed entries. The proxy keeps giving this exception:

```
Riga 22:             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(proxyURL);
Riga 23:             request.Method = "GET";
Riga 24:             HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Riga 25: 
Riga 26:             if (response.StatusCode.ToString().ToLower() == "ok")

[SocketException (0x274c): Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato 213.92.16.191:80]


System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +269
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +649

[WebException: Impossibile effettuare la connessione al server remoto.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1126
   Proxy.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\andrea\documents\visual_studio_2010\websites\leafhouse\Proxy.aspx.cs:24
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

This is my proxy.aspx page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public partial class Proxy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string proxyURL = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            proxyURL = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["u"].ToString());

        if (proxyURL != string.Empty)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(proxyURL);
            request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode.ToString().ToLower() == "ok")
            {
                string contentType = response.ContentType;
                Stream content = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader contentReader = new StreamReader(content);
                Response.ContentType = contentType;
                Response.Write(contentReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

}

And this is the jquery i use:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "proxy.aspx?u=" + encodeURI("http://" + serverAddress + ":82") + "/RSSReaderSubscriptions.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find('url').each(function (index, element) {
            if (index < 3) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "proxy.aspx?u=" + encodeURI($(this).text()),
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (data) {
                        parseRSS(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("error");
                });
            }
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error");
});
```

How can i make the proxy load rss feeds?
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I think that if you install IIS AFTER you install .NET 4 Asp doesn't register itself to IIS so you always get `error 500` (maybe this is true also for previous versions of IIS but i can't check this).
The solution is to open the command line (i did as administrator) and move to the folder:

```
cd %windir%/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.xxxxx/
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Now you should be good to go, enjoy!

Comment: Here's a bit more info about this tool on [MSDN](http://www.varindersandhu.in/2010/12/13/asp-net-iis-registration-tool-aspnet_regiis-exe/). Good to know, thanks as well!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like more like a network/connection problem than a bug in your code.

Can you connect 'manually' to the feed's url? Maybe some proxy is blocking the access to them...

**Some remarks:**

- To do these kind of jobs, it's better to use HttpHandlers instead of aspx pages to avoid the full (and time/resources consuming) [Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). There is a very insteresting article about this on Encosia [here](http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/).
- It is better to use the `data` property of the jquery ajax options object to pass data and not construct a querystring as you are currently doing.

Hope this helps a bit, d.

Comment: Thanks for the HttpHandler advice. I switched to it as it seems what i was searching for exactly! For the issue, read my answer.